# SQL LIKE Operator doesn't work with Asian Languages (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql-server, select, unicode, collation, nvarchar

I have a SQL Server database column that is of type NVarchar and is filled with standard Persian characters. when I'm trying to run a very simple query on it which incorporates the LIKE operator, the resultset becomes empty although I know the query term is present in the table. Here is the very simple example query which doesn't act correctly:

```
SELECT * FROM T_Contacts WHERE C_ContactName LIKE '%ف%'
```

ف is a Persian character and the ContactName column contains multiple entries which contain that character.

Please tell me how should I rewrite the expression or what change should I apply. Note that my database's collation is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Also, if those values are stored as `NVARCHAR` (which I hope they are!!), you should **always** use the `N'..'` prefix for any string literals to make sure you don't get any unwanted conversions back to non-Unicode `VARCHAR`.

So you should be searching:

```
SELECT * FROM T_Contacts 
WHERE C_ContactName COLLATE Persian_100_CI_AS LIKE N'%ف%'
```

Answer (score 4):

Shouldn't it be:

```
 SELECT * FROM T_Contacts WHERE C_ContactName LIKE N'%ف%'
```

ie, with the `N` in front of the comparing string, so it treats it like an `nvarchar`?